# How to get all collections of the current scene?

Tags: python, scene, collections

*I'd like to get all collections in the current scene and can't find a way to do that.* I found `bpy.data.collections` to get all collections stored in the blend and `C.scene.collection.children` to return the first level of sub-collections. However, I can't find out which collection is linked to each scene. I wonder if there is a simple way like iterating through the objects in context `C.scene.objects`?

**Q:** How to get all collections of the current scene?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Recursively walk the tree.**

Similarly to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137866/15543 and [Sorting Collections Alphabetically in the Outliner](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157562/sorting-collections-alphabetically-in-the-outliner)

```
import bpy

def traverse_tree(t):
    yield t
    for child in t.children:
        yield from traverse_tree(child)

coll = bpy.context.scene.collection

for c in traverse_tree(coll):
    print(c.name)
```

**Look at ID users**

It is most likely a lot quicker to run over the collections and check if they are in use by the scene. If a collection is linked anywhere in the hierarchy of a scene's collection tree, then the scene is a user of the collection.

```
>>> collections_in_scene = [
        c for c in D.collections 
        if C.scene.user_of_id(c)
    ]
>>> collections_in_scene
[bpy.data.collections['Collection 1'], bpy.data.collections['Collection 1 1'], bpy.data.collections['Collection 1 1 1']]
```

Comment: This solution is "WOW", but I wonder one thing, what does it change to use C.view_layer.layer_collection.collection with C.scene.collection?

Comment: They're often the same.  `coll = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.collection`

Comment: What is the difference between the `bpy.context.scene.collection` and `bpy.data.collections` because with the second one in my case I am getting some extra collections from the ones that are visible in the outliner.

Comment: A blend can appear totally empty. The data we see is linked to a scene. Just as an object with no parent really has the scene as a parent, the scene collection is the root of collections in a scene without the need to also define it in `bpy.data.collections`

Comment: So I guess it is always safer to go with the `bpy.context.scene.collection` rather the `bpy.data.collections`.

Comment: Use `context.collection` would be my suggestion. Or to be sure to be sure `context.collection or scene.collection` Unless  I'm creating objects rarely or never use `bpy.data`  eg if you are interested in an object "Foo" `scene.objects.get("Foo")` is in the scene, whereas `bpy.data.objects.get("Foo")` may not be. Similarly with collections.

Comment: Thanks for the details, appreciated ;-).