# Python: How to move collection into another collection?

Tags: python, collections

Let's say we have collections A and B directly under the main Scene Collection. Is it possible to move collection B inside collection A using python?

When I do this manually (drag and drop), the Info panel shows only "bpy.ops.outliner.collection_drop()
", so that didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you just have to [`.unlink(collection)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionChildren.html#bpy.types.CollectionChildren.unlink) the sub-collection from its current parent and then [`.link(collection)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionChildren.html#bpy.types.CollectionChildren.link) it to the new parent collection.

Problem is there is currently no way *(attribute)* to get the *parent collection* so we need to find the parent in the first place. I'd suggest create a lookup (dict) to store the relationship and then *(un)link*:

```
import bpy

def traverse_tree(t):
    yield t
    for child in t.children:
        yield from traverse_tree(child)

def parent_lookup(coll):
    parent_lookup = {}
    for coll in traverse_tree(coll):
        for c in coll.children.keys():
            parent_lookup.setdefault(c, coll)
    return parent_lookup


C = bpy.context

# Get all collections of the scene and their parents in a dict
coll_scene = C.scene.collection
coll_parents = parent_lookup(coll_scene)

# Get collection references
coll_target = coll_scene.children.get("Collection")
active_coll = C.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection

# Get parent of *active_coll*
active_coll_parent = coll_parents.get(active_coll.name)

if active_coll_parent:
    # Unlink *active_coll*
    active_coll_parent.children.unlink(active_coll)

    # Link *active_coll* to *coll_target*
    coll_target.children.link(active_coll)
```

`traverse_tree(t)` function from [How to get all collections of the current scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167889/31447)

Comment: Thank you. It works! Out of curiosity commented out the unlink() call and found that the collection got duplicated.