# How do I get Collection ID from bpy.data.collections["CollectionNAME"]?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

I'm currently creating a script that I'm using to organize a lot of assets at once (I will share it once it works).

I want to use [`move_to_collection`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.move_to_collection) so that I don't have to keep track of all the collections where the asset currently is. But `move_to_collection` wants a Collection ID, and I only have the collection object retrieved from `bpy.data.collections` and I would love to get the collection ID from it.

Comment: Suggest do not use the operator. It is pretty easy to unlink and re-link the objects: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175146/moving-many-objects-to-a-new-collection/175152#175152 Also to be on the safe side, consider to iterate through the collections in the current scene (`bpy.context.scene*`) not iterating over data blocks (`bpy.data*`)

Comment: How to move a collection: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172559/python-how-to-move-collection-into-another-collection/172579#172579 (in case)

Comment: Are you sure, I will not get an error if I unlink from a collection but the object is not in it?

Comment: Not *exactly* sure what you're talking about... All I can say is that using the index operator `Collection["CollectionName"]` is even more error prone than anything else. Suggest add more details to your question. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To reiterate comment 1 above https://devtalk.blender.org/t/where-to-find-collection-index-for-moving-an-object/3289/2?u=batfinger