# Check, using name, if a collection exists in blend & is linked to scene

Tags: python, collections

I have a script that creates a new collection but if I run it again it adds a new collection named "Personal Collection.001" and so on, what I would like to tell to the script is that if that collection name is in the scene then don't make a new one.

```
import bpy

myCol = bpy.data.collections.new('Personal collection')
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(myCol) #Creates a new collection


for myCol in bpy.data.collections:
    if myCol.name == "Personal Collection":
        print ("Collection found in scene")
```

Cheers,
Juan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
import bpy


collectionFound = False

print("START **************")

for myCol in bpy.data.collections:
    print(myCol.name)
    if myCol.name == "Personal Collection":
        collectionFound = True
        print ("Collection found in scene")
        break
        
        
if collectionFound == False:
    myCol = bpy.data.collections.new("Personal Collection")
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(myCol) #Creates a new collection
    print("created")
else:
    print("exists already")
```

and be careful: you mismatched upper- and lowercase!! String comparison is case sensitive.

Comment: `collectionFound == False` can be `"Personal Collection" not in bpy.data.collections`.

Comment: sorry, i do not understand what do you mean?

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. Yes you are right about the case, there are so many small things that easily can be overlooked.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: According to PEP8, variable names should be lower_case: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Comment: i just used his code...but thanks for the note.

Comment: @JuanCarlos: to have a cleaner and more safe solution you should use batFingers answer.

Answer (score 11):

**Check it exists and is linked to scene.**

IMO Two tests required here, one to test if collection exists, and secondly if it is linked at any level to the current scene.  A quick test for the latter is to see if the scene is a user of the collection.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

# name of collection
name = "Foo"

scene = context.scene

coll = bpy.data.collections.get(name)
# if it doesn't exist create it
if coll is None:
    coll = bpy.data.collections.new(name)
# if it is not linked to scene colleciton treelink it
if not scene.user_of_id(coll):
    context.collection.children.link(coll)
```

Related

[How to get all collections of the current scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167878/how-to-get-all-collections-of-the-current-scene/167889#167889)